# Using MJML with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm using the following package with my Laravel 9 application.

https://github.com/asahasrabuddhe/laravel-mjml

Following the documentation, the following piece **works** in my Mailable class:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->to($this->lead->email)
        ->subject($subject)
        ->mjml('emails.lead-created', [
            'lead' => $this->lead
        ]);
}
```

In some of my Mailable classes, I'm using the `evelope` and `content` functions instead of `build`. How can I use mjml in these cases?

The following **does not work** (Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content::__construct(): Argument #1 ($view) must be of type ?string, App\Mail\SalesAddedToLead given):

```
public function content()
{
    return new Content(
        view: $this->mjml('emails.sales-added'),
    );
}
```

How would I use this package with the `content` function?